# NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for User(no database connection):Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Just installed devise and used the generator to create the user model. The error forms with `rake db:migrate`.

routes.rb:

```
Bookmarkit::Application.routes.draw do
  get "bookmarks/create"
  get "bookmarks/update"
  get "bookmarks/destroy"
  get "bookmarks/read"

  devise_for :users

  resources :bookmarks

  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

I've tried:

1. removing user.rb and re-running the generator.
2. re-running bundle just to make sure.
3. moving the location of `devise_for :users` in routes.rb.
4. error goes away when I comment out `devise_for :users`

Update: I didn't install devise before trying to `rake db:migrate`. Removing the devise reference from routes.rb, installing the gem (using `rails generate devise:install`) and executing `rake db:migrate` fixed the issue. Thanks for the help though team. I appreciate it!

Comment: `rake db:create` done?

Comment: Very good explanation of usage of [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) carefully follow this